# How do I retrieve the value of an HTML textbox in C# using MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I am new to MonoDevelop, C#, and Linux. To learn how things work, I'm trying to make a simple web page to input the height and width of a rectangle, then use a submit button to calculate and display the area.

I have two problems. First, I can't get the submit button to actually do anything. Second, I'm having trouble getting the value of the textboxes in the C# code. Once I get it, I think I can handle the values okay to calculate the area and spit it back out. The Request.Form commands were my point of problem I believe.

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<body>
 <div>
  Height <input type="text" name="inHeight" value=1 /><br />
  Width <input type="text" name="inWidth" value=1 /><br />
  <br />
  <input type="button" name="btnCalculateArea" value="Calculate Area" onclick="CalculateArea()" /><br />
  <br />
  <%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %>
 </div>
</body>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace rectangle_area.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public string strHeight;
        public string strWidth;
        public int intHeight;
        public int intWidth;
        public double dblArea;

        public ActionResult Index ()
        {
            return View ();
        }

        public ViewResult CalculateArea ()
        {
            strHeight = Request.Form ["inHeight"];
            strWidth = Request.Form ["inWidth"];

            if (strHeight != null && strWidth != null) {
                intHeight = Convert.ToInt16 (strHeight);
                intWidth = Convert.ToInt16 (strWidth);

                dblArea = intHeight * intWidth;

                ViewData ["Message"] = "The area of this rectangle is " + dblArea + " square units.";
            } else {
                ViewData ["Message"] = "Please enter values for the Height and Width.";
            }

            return View ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to call the `CalculateArea` in the `HomeController`, as I can understand from your code, but in your markup, you just bind to the click event of your button a function with the same name. This will not work. You have to bind there a function that makes an ajax call to your controller. Furthermore if there isn't any script loaded with a function with the name `CalculateArea` you should get an exception, if you open the developer tools of your browser and look at the console's output.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am getting a ReferenceError in Firefox that this function is not defined. I'll try to figure out how to make the appropriate calls.

Any thoughts on getting the appropriate value from the textbox into the C# code to make the calculations?

Answer (score 0):

> You have to bind there a function that makes an ajax call to your controller.

Thanks for the direction, Christos! With the help of a friend and more research, I got it working. Here's what I ended up with:

```html
<head runat="server">
 <title>Calculate the area of a rectangle</title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var serviceURL = '/Home/CalculateArea';
   
   $('#calcBtn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: serviceURL,
                 data: { inHeight: $("#inHeight").val(), inWidth: $("#inWidth").val() },
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: successFunc,
                 error: errorFunc
             });
   });
   
   function successFunc(data, status) {     
                alert(data);
            }
   
            function errorFunc() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  Height <input type="text" id="inHeight" value=2 /><br />
  Width <input type="text" id="inWidth" value=3 /><br />
  <br />
  <input id="calcBtn" type="submit" value="Calculate Area" /><br />
  <br />
  
 </div>
</body>
```

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CalculateArea ()
    {
        strHeight = Request.Params ["inHeight"];
        strWidth = Request.Params ["inWidth"];

        if (strHeight != null && strWidth != null) {
            intHeight = Convert.ToInt16 (strHeight);
            intWidth = Convert.ToInt16 (strWidth);

            dblArea = intHeight * intWidth;

            ViewData ["Message"] = "The area of this rectangle is " + dblArea + " square units.";
        } else {
            ViewData ["Message"] = "Please enter values between 0 and 999.";
        }

        return Json(ViewData["Message"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```